# Change Canvas color except path

Tags: android, canvas, android-view, android-canvas

I have a custom view that extends `ImageView`. After setting an image I start by highlighting something on the image. When I press a button I want to make the image black except for that part of the path. Is there a way how I can achieve that?

What I have tried initially was to create a second bitmap with a second canvas but now displaying it, while drawing on the main canvas also draw with transparent paint on the black canvas and on the final step merge them together. I could not achieve drawing transparent on the black canvas.

```
@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
class BlackImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    var path: Path = Path()
    var transparentPath: Path = Path()

    var paint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        isDither = true
        strokeWidth = 25f
        color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.highlight, null)
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
    }

    var transparentPaint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        isDither = true
        strokeWidth = 25f
        color = Color.TRANSPARENT
        xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
    }

    private lateinit var blackBitmap: Bitmap
    private lateinit var extraCanvas: Canvas

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        blackBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        extraCanvas = Canvas(blackBitmap)
        extraCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        event?.let {
            when (it.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    path.moveTo(event.x, event.y)
                    transparentPath.moveTo(event.x, event.y)

                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    path.lineTo(event.x, event.y)
                    transparentPath.lineTo(event.x, event.y)
                    invalidate()
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {

                }
                else -> {
                    invalidate()
                    return true
                }
            }
        }

        invalidate()
        return true
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
//        canvas?.drawBitmap(blackBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
//        canvas?.drawPath(transparentPath, transparentPaint)
        canvas?.drawPath(path, paint)
    }

}
```

Comment: need an image example what do you want

Comment: You should use porter duff operations. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode